# Use Stateful components in the React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, stateful

Imagine application with tabs, that allow user to switch between different areas where user can enter different information.

I want to create a switch-component that represents this tabs and render another component with user related information based on the current router state. The main difficulty is the fact that child component is stateful - they can already contain some text entered by user. I attempt to implement this component with simple `react-router` in the following way:

```
class Application extends React.PureComponent {
    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        const items = ["A", "B", "C"];
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    <ul>
                        {items.map((item, i) =>
                            (<li key={i}>
                                <Link to={"/" + item}>{item}</Link>
                            </li>))
                        }
                    </ul>
                </header>
                <SwitchComponent items={items}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SwitchComponent extends React.PureComponent<{items: string[]}> {
    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        const { items } = this.props;
        return (
            <Switch>
                {items.map((item, index) =>
                    <Route key={index} path={"/" + item} render={
                        () => (<StatefulComponent {...item}/>)
                    }/>)
                }
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

class StatefulComponent extends React.PureComponent<{}, {text: string}> {
    public state = {
        text: "",
    };
    public onChange(text: string) {
        this.setState({text});
    }
    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        const { text } = this.state;
        return (
            <input value={text} onChange={
                (event) => this.onChange.bind(this)(event.target.value)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Here I implement a simple `Application` component that contains navigation-area implemented via `<Link>` components and content-area that includes switch by route.

This implementation doesn't preserve `<StatefulComponent>` state, because `<SwitchComponent>` recreated every time user switch to another link.

How can I preserve state of my components in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. React router unmounts unneeded `<Route>` components (the ones that do not match, only one `<Route>` component is mounted when using `react-router`).

Comment: Are there any extension for `react-router` or similar components that is capable to preserve stateful components?

Comment: Never heard of anything like this. But you can preserve stateful component by using only one `Route` which would look like this: `<Route path={"/:item"}>`. In `StatefulComponent` you can check `props.match` to check the value of `:item` in any given moment. Also don't forget to change your render prop for route to make it pass down its props, like: `(props) => (<StatefulComponent {...props} {...item}/>)`